# Using dd command to extract lzma file from within firmware binary

Tags: linux, command-line, router

Here's a direct link to the firmware referenced:

ftp://ftp2.dlink.com/PRODUCTS/DIR-601/REVB/DIR-601_REVB_FIRMWARE_2.01.ZIP

I'm having trouble extracting the file system from this particular router more specifically by using the `dd` command to extract the kernel within the firmware binary.

My steps:

I used `binwalk dir601_revB_FW_201.bin` to find that the lzma in question is located at byte #148 (so fairly early on). I tried to extract this lzma archive by using the following command:

```
dd if=dir601_revB_FW_201.bin skip=148 bs=1 count=8388608 of=kernel.lzma
```

Where `count` is the dictionary size of the archive but to no avail because when I try to `unlzma` my extracted archive it keeps giving me `compressed data is corrupt` error.

How to extract and uncompress this archive?

Comment: Doesn't binwalk itself have an option to extract?

Answer (score 2):

In my Debian

```
binwalk -e dir601_revB_FW_201.bin
```

generates (among others) a file `./_dir601_revB_FW_201.bin.extracted/94`. Below is my procedure to get the same file with `dd` and `unlzma`, like you tried.

---

I run your original command and the one from [the other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1448023/432690). In both cases I could do the extraction with `7za` (with an error though) but not with sole `unlzma`. I was able to improve the approach so `unlzma` works.

First of all your `count=8388608` is obviously wrong because `dir601_revB_FW_201.bin` is *smaller*. The right number is in the header:

> ```
> uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, […] image size: 819799 bytes, […]
> ```

Your command should have been

```
dd if=dir601_revB_FW_201.bin skip=148 bs=1 count=819799 of=x.lzma
```

If I extract 1 byte less, `unlzma x.lzma` in my Debian will complain with `unexpected end of input`. If I extract 1 byte more, it will complain with `compressed data is corrupt`.

The exact number `819799` triggers no complains from the tool, everything works. After this I can `binwalk x` (as the other answer already noted).

The `x` file is identical to `94` obtained with `binwalk -e` (confirmed with `cmp`).

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change a bit your `dd` options. Try it like this:

```
dd if=dir601_revB_FW_201.bin ibs=1 skip=148 of=x.lzma
```

Then you can uncompress it with `lzma -d x.lzma` and if you `binwalk x` you'll see something like this:

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
77724         0x12F9C         Certificate in DER format (x509 v3), header length: 4, sequence length: 30
1769504       0x1B0020        Linux kernel version 2.6.31
1832080       0x1BF490        CRC32 polynomial table, little endian
2081839       0x1FC42F        Neighborly text, "neighbor %.2x%.2x.%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x lost on port %d(%s)(%s)"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you use `unlzma` or another tool? Your command produces *exactly* the same `*.lzma` file as the OP's command. If they couldn't proceed in the first place, your answer changes nothing.

Comment: I used `lzma -d`. It's basically the standard tool for `.lzma` files.

Comment: Apparently your `lzma -d` (and probably `unlzma`) does accept archives with trailing garbage. The OP's `unlzma` doesn't and I guess their `lzma -d` won't.

Comment: Well, I use the Debian repository's `LZMA command line tool 9.22`, if it's of any help. But still, once you have `x.lzma` you may `dd if=x.lzma count=1791 bs=512  of=y.lzma` and single out only the `lzma` archive in file `y.lzma`.